# Could a species that doesn't sleep invent technology?

Tags: technological-development, sleep

Could a species that does not naturally sleep invent complex technologies as humans have?

Sleep is important to processing information, and high technology evidently requires much more information than a typical natural environment (especially one in which a sleepless animal may live)

Could this informational limitation be overcome with proper pacing, or are sleepless species unable to truly progress?

Comment: In your preliminary researches, have you found any animal species which doesn't sleep?

Comment: @L.Dutch Yes, I have. Sleeplessness is mainly in pelagic fish

Comment: This seems like a problem to figure. Sure there are animals that don't show signs of sleeping, but they all come from a zone of absolute darkness and extra-scarce food where having a brain complex enough for inventing technology would be an outright detriment to their survival to begin with.

Comment: A species which does not sleep must have a brain which works in a way quite different from the way our brain works. Onm what basis do you say that *for such a species* "sleep is important to processing information"? In insects, molting is essential for the process of growth. Would an insect scientist be right in saying that growth is impossible in a species which does not molt?

Comment: @AlexP Real species that don't sleep live in environments with much less stimulus than those that do sleep, which implies a relationship to information even in these species

Comment: @IchthysKing: Right, correct. Which means that the alien species in the question is not from this world, or at least it is not from a mainstream evolutionary line. Which means that its brain works in a way quite different from the way our brain works.

Comment: @AlexP I'm pretty sure that tuna fish aren't aliens

Comment: Sleep has an unknown biological purpose, and might be the result of an early path dependence issue. It's unclear if alien organisms would need sleep at all. If they don't, there's no reason to suppose that they couldn't also be as intelligent as humans. When/if artificial (general) intelligence is invented, there's no reason to suppose that this will require sleep or an analog thereof.

Comment: This question seems to suggest that creativity only occurs when one is asleep. I don't see how the logical path follows. If a race has evolved without a need to sleep, then they must have a different mechanism that serves the same purpose, or it's constructed in such a way to not need it.

Comment: It does make me wonder...we are looking at this from Earth evidence, but Earth rotates day and night. How much of Earth-based sleep is actually from animals specializing in day vs night. Nocturnal or not. The sleep isn't to "process information" so much as to get them through the part of the day they aren't specialized for. Makes me wonder what sleep patterns would look like in life developed on a tidally locked planet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really depends entirely upon how you want to design your unsleeping species.

If you want your alien species to be limited because it doesn't sleep, then this will make a good explanation for it.

If you want to give your alien species a brain that can simultaneously remain conscious while its brain is processing and defragging its data, then the lack of sleep will not be a limiting factor.

So **It Depends** on how you want your story to go.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer is "**no**", unless you wanted to count **[unihemispheric sleep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unihemispheric_slow-wave_sleep)** as "not sleeping".

In unihemispheric sleep, only half the brain sleeps at a time, so the animal is never *fully* asleep. This has been observed in dolphins and a few species of whales, so it seems applicable to intelligent species. So if you're inventing an alien species that is known to "never sleep" but is intelligent and has technology, this may be how they do it. To the human observer, they never sleep, but really they enter restful states where they are sleeping with half their brain at a time, remaining alert with the other half.

Baby dolphins and baby orcas don't sleep for the first couple of months.....but after that they do sleep, so I don't think there are any examples of "developed brains" (adults that are smarter than a bullfrog) that require no sleep of any type at all. It does imply that sleep is necessary.